# Pandas bar plot with both categorical and numerical data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe named 'data' with data similar to the following table. I want to plot them in python as bar plots.

```
Name    X   Y   Z   Activity
AAA1    0.0 0.0 2.0 Low
AAA2    0.0 2.0 6.0 Medium
AAA3    1.0 2.0 3.0 High
AAA4    2.0 1.0 4.0 High
```

What I tried is, with a bit of setting color and style,

```
sns.set(style="white", context="talk", palette="husl")
data.plot.bar(x='Name', width=.8)
```

While this plots a bar diagram showing X, Y, and Z for each Name (9 bars in total), I cannot figure out a way of showing the 'Activity' corresponding to each 'Name' in the bar diagrams. It will be nice if I can somehow show this categorical column graphically, either by color or by some style, on the top of the bar charts. I am using Python 3.7.0 with 
Pandas 0.23.3,
matplotlib 2.2.2, and
seaborn version 0.9.0 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this solution fit you, but at first I group data by *Activity* and *Name* and then I plot barplot. Example (I get your DataFrame):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.groupby(['Activity','Name']).sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

And the result
[image: Barplot]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way of sorting the bars by Activity? Can we have activity going from low to high?

Comment: Oh got it. Just had to add `sort=False` inside the groupby option. Accepting the answer now.